# Smooks - How to map choices element from xml to java

Tags: java, binding, smooks

is possible in smooks (version 1.5.1) map only one generated element from two choices element to java field?

Example:

xsd file:

```
<complexType name="timeType">
  <sequence>
    <choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <element name="time"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <complexType>
        <attribute name="v" type="dateTime"/>
      </complexType>
    </element>
    <element name="time2"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <complexType>
        <attribute name="v" type="dateTime"/>
      </complexType>
    </element>
    </choice>
</complexType>
```

a) xml file1:

```
<parent>
  <time v="2001-12-31T12:00:00"/>  
</parent>
```

b) xml file2:

```
<parent> 
  <time2 v="2002-12-31T12:00:00"/>
</parent>
```

smooks mapping

```
<jb:bean beanId="timeRef" class="someClass" createOnElement="parent">
  <!--  only if is generated (present) time element map this time element-->
  <jb:value property="fromHour" data="time/@v" decoder="DateTime" />

  <!-- only if is generated (present) time2 element map time2 element -->
  <jb:value property="fromHour" data="time2/@v" decoder="DateTime" />
</jb:bean>
```

How I tell to smooks, that I want save only one generated element? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
<jb:bean beanId="parentBeanId" class="parentMapClass" createOnElement="parentElement">
      ...
      <jb:wiring property="property" beanIdRef="timeRef" />
      <jb:wiring property="property" beanIdRef="timeIntervalRef" />
      ...
</jb:bean>

<jb:bean beanId="timeRef" class="someClass" createOnElement="parentElement/time">
      <jb:value property="fromHour" data="time/@v" decoder="DateTime" />
      <jb:value property="toHour" data="time/@v" decoder="DateTime" />
</jb:bean>

   <jb:bean beanId="timeIntervalRef" class="someClass" createOnElement="parentElement/timeInterval">
      <jb:value property="fromHour" data="timeInterval/@v" decoder="TimeIntervalFrom" />
      <jb:value property="toHour" data="timeInterval/@v" decoder="TimeIntervalTo" />
   </jb:bean>
```